# Can't see difference in the three searches - full text, semantic and vector searches

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

New to AI search and trying to understand some fundamentals. Would appreciate if someone could help with few questions: I have uploaded the `notebooks` at https://github.com/manuchadha1979/aisearchnotebooks if someone will like to run them

I have created an AI search service in Azure with 3 indexes `hotel-finder-fulltext`,`hotel-finder-semantic` and `hotel-finder-vector-semantic`. I want to understand the difference between the three types of services?

The schema is the following (with differences as needed for semantic and vector-semantic)

```
# Specify the index schema
name = index_name
fields = [
        SimpleField(name="HotelId", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True),
        SearchableField(name="HotelName", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, sortable=True),
        SearchableField(name="Description", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, analyzer_name="en.lucene"),
        SearchableField(name="Description_fr", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, analyzer_name="fr.lucene"),
        SearchableField(name="Category", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),

        SearchableField(name="Tags", collection=True, type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True),

        SimpleField(name="ParkingIncluded", type=SearchFieldDataType.Boolean, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
        SimpleField(name="LastRenovationDate", type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
        SimpleField(name="Rating", type=SearchFieldDataType.Double, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),

        ComplexField(name="Address", fields=[
            SearchableField(name="StreetAddress", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
            SearchableField(name="City", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="StateProvince", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="PostalCode", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="Country", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
        ])
    ]
cors_options = CorsOptions(allowed_origins=["*"], max_age_in_seconds=60)
scoring_profiles = []
suggester = [{'name': 'sg', 'source_fields': ['Tags', 'Address/City', 'Address/Country']}]
```

Semantic has additional parameters

```
semantic_config = SemanticConfiguration(
    name="my-semantic-config",
    prioritized_fields=SemanticPrioritizedFields(
        title_field=SemanticField(field_name="HotelName"),
        keywords_fields=[SemanticField(field_name="Category")],
        content_fields=[SemanticField(field_name="Description")]
    )
)

semantic_search = SemanticSearch(configurations=[semantic_config])
```

Vector's specific fields are

```
SearchField(name="HotelNameVector",
    type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single), 
    searchable=True, 
    vector_search_dimensions=1536,
    vector_search_profile_name="my-vector-profile"),
    SearchField(name="DescriptionVector",
    type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single), 
    searchable=True, 
    vector_search_dimensions=1536,
    vector_search_profile_name="my-vector-profile")
    ]

hnswParameters = HnswParameters(m=4,ef_construction= 400, ef_search= 500, metric= "cosine")
vectorSearchAlgorithm = HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(name = "my-hnsw-vector-config-1",parameters=hnswParameters)
vectorSearchProfile = VectorSearchProfile(name="my-vector-profile",algorithm_configuration_name="my-hnsw-vector-config-1")

...
vector_search = VectorSearch(profiles = [vectorSearchProfile],algorithms=[vectorSearchAlgorithm])
```

I created the index as follows (with vector and semantic specific fields as needed)

```
index = SearchIndex(
    name=name,
    fields=fields,
    vector_search=vector_search,
    semantic_search = semantic_search, //present for semantic and vector index
    scoring_profiles=scoring_profiles, //present only for vector index
    suggesters=suggester)

try:
    result = admin_client.create_index(index)
    print ('Index', result.name, 'created')
except Exception as ex:
    print (ex)
```

The following is the data in the indexes. Both `full-text` and `semantic` have same data. `vector` has additional vector fields `HotelNameVector` and `DescriptionVector` to store vectors for `HotelName` and `Description` fields which I created using `azure open ai` `embedding` model.

```
documents = [
    {
    "@search.action": "upload",
    "HotelId": "1",
    "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
    "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
    "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
    "Category": "Boutique",
    "Tags": [ "pool", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
    "ParkingIncluded": "false",
    "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
    "Rating": "3.60",
    "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
        "City": "New York",
        "StateProvince": "NY",
        "PostalCode": "10022",
        "Country": "USA"
        }
    },
    {
    "@search.action": "upload",
    "HotelId": "2",
    "HotelName": "Twin Dome Motel",
    "Description": "The hotel is situated in a  nineteenth century plaza, which has been expanded and renovated to the highest architectural standards to create a modern, functional and first-class hotel in which art and unique historical elements coexist with the most modern comforts.",
    "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est situé dans une place du XIXe siècle, qui a été agrandie et rénovée aux plus hautes normes architecturales pour créer un hôtel moderne, fonctionnel et de première classe dans lequel l'art et les éléments historiques uniques coexistent avec le confort le plus moderne.",
    "Category": "Boutique",
    "Tags": [ "pool", "free wifi", "concierge" ],
    "ParkingIncluded": "false",
    "LastRenovationDate": "1979-02-18T00:00:00Z",
    "Rating": "3.60",
    "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "140 University Town Center Dr",
        "City": "Sarasota",
        "StateProvince": "FL",
        "PostalCode": "34243",
        "Country": "USA"
        }
    },
    {
    "@search.action": "upload",
    "HotelId": "3",
    "HotelName": "Triple Landscape Hotel",
    "Description": "The Hotel stands out for its gastronomic excellence under the management of William Dough, who advises on and oversees all of the Hotel's restaurant services.",
    "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est situé dans une place du XIXe siècle, qui a été agrandie et rénovée aux plus hautes normes architecturales pour créer un hôtel moderne, fonctionnel et de première classe dans lequel l'art et les éléments historiques uniques coexistent avec le confort le plus moderne.",
    "Category": "Resort and Spa",
    "Tags": [ "air conditioning", "bar", "continental breakfast" ],
    "ParkingIncluded": "true",
    "LastRenovationDate": "2015-09-20T00:00:00Z",
    "Rating": "4.80",
    "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "3393 Peachtree Rd",
        "City": "Atlanta",
        "StateProvince": "GA",
        "PostalCode": "30326",
        "Country": "USA"
        }
    },
    {
    "@search.action": "upload",
    "HotelId": "4",
    "HotelName": "Sublime Cliff Hotel",
    "Description": "Sublime Cliff Hotel is located in the heart of the historic center of Sublime in an extremely vibrant and lively area within short walking distance to the sites and landmarks of the city and is surrounded by the extraordinary beauty of churches, buildings, shops and monuments. Sublime Cliff is part of a lovingly restored 1800 palace.",
    "Description_fr": "Le sublime Cliff Hotel est situé au coeur du centre historique de sublime dans un quartier extrêmement animé et vivant, à courte distance de marche des sites et monuments de la ville et est entouré par l'extraordinaire beauté des églises, des bâtiments, des commerces et Monuments. Sublime Cliff fait partie d'un Palace 1800 restauré avec amour.",
    "Category": "Boutique",
    "Tags": [ "concierge", "view", "24-hour front desk service" ],
    "ParkingIncluded": "true",
    "LastRenovationDate": "1960-02-06T00:00:00Z",
    "Rating": "4.60",
    "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "7400 San Pedro Ave",
        "City": "San Antonio",
        "StateProvince": "TX",
        "PostalCode": "78216",
        "Country": "USA"
        }
    }
]
```

additional fields for `vector` index

```
"HotelNameVector":[...] //float values
"DescriptionVector": [...] //float values
```

If I run the following query I get different results though I don't understand why the `semantic` and `vector` one didn't give the right result

```
results =  search_client.search(query_type='simple',
    search_text="which hotel has rating of 4 or over?" ,
    select='HotelName,HotelId')

for result in results:
    print(result["@search.score"])
    print(result["@search.reranker_score"])
    print(result["HotelName"])
```

result for `full-text`: Question - Why the ranking field wasn't considered to find the fight answer? Is it because the search is based on keyword matching and doesn't understand concept of ranking.

```
2.1942296
None
Twin Dome Motel
1.0144587
None
Triple Landscape Hotel
0.9284746
None
Sublime Cliff Hotel
0.51237863
None
Secret Point Motel
```

Question - Running the same on `semantic` shortlisted the results but picked the wrong hotel (Twin has rating under 4

```
results =  search_client.search(query_type='semantic', semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
    search_text="which restaurant has rating of 4 or over?", 
    select='HotelName,Description,Category', query_caption='extractive')

for result in results:
    print(result["@search.score"])
    print(result["@search.reranker_score"])
    print(result["HotelName"])
```

result:

```
0.26301134
0.9669117331504822
Triple Landscape Hotel
1.6842916
0.061580806970596313
Twin Dome Motel
```

The query on `vector` search (after converting the query into vector` gave the following result

```
vectors = [...]
vectorized_queries = VectorizedQuery(vector = vectors,k_nearest_neighbors=7,fields="DescriptionVector",exhaustive=True,kind="vector")
results =  search_client.search(query_type='semantic', semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
    search_text="which restaurant has rating of 4 or over?", 
    select='HotelName,Description,Category', query_caption='extractive',
    vector_queries = [vectorized_queries]
    )

for result in results:
    print(result["@search.score"])
    print(result["@search.reranker_score"])
    print(result["HotelName"])
```

result

```
0.03306011110544205
0.9661457538604736
Triple Landscape Hotel
0.01587301678955555
0.31893375515937805
Sublime Cliff Hotel
0.03306011110544205
0.061580806970596313
Twin Dome Motel
0.016129031777381897
0.023284239694476128
Secret Point Motel
```

Question - Why did vector return `Twin` and `secret` hotels? As I had specified that the field to search for vector similarity is the `description` field, which doesn't specify ranking, how did `vector` generate the answer? Is it just by chance the the hotels with rating 4 or over are top 2 while the hotels with rating lower than 4 are bottom 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `full-text`: the match criteria are usually whole terms or phrases, with or without operators. Any field attributed as "searchable" in the index schema is a candidate for this parameter.

So, in your case, the rating is **Double** and it is only filterable, not searchable. Even if you convert it to **String**, you still won't get correct results because it goes for matching terms and phrases.

**Example**:

If you give the search query like this:

```
which hotel has a rating of 4 or over?
```

you still get the same result, as `4` is not present in any of the `Rating` field records. If you give it like below:

```
4.80
```

Then you will get the document matching this one.

`Full-text` uses the [BM25](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-similarity-and-scoring) algorithm for scoring.

In `semantic`: It adds secondary ranking over the initial result set generated using BM25 or RRF. This secondary ranking uses multi-lingual, deep learning models adapted from Microsoft Bing to promote the most semantically relevant results.

Summarization and scoring are the two steps for ranking the result set; the summarization output is a summary string for each document, composed of the most relevant information from each field. Here, the field refers to **title**, **keywords**, and **content**. It matches for the keywords around the context in content, which is in natural language form.

In your case, **which** and **restaurant** are matched with your results. There is an additional option, `query_answer`, while searching text that you can use for text summarization.

In `vector`: since it represents the content in numeric vector form rather than plain text, it doesn't look for matching exact terms; it matches on vectors that are the most similar to the query. So it doesn't check for the meaning of your query; it simply checks the similar vector with the help of an algorithm and ranks it.

In all of these approaches, your query doesn't give you the exact solution since the rating is not plain text data; it is of double type and only filterable.

To search the data with your query, any field which is **searchable** and mentions `the hotel rating is 4.8 and famous` kind of texts, then you will get the results, though with ranking and multiple results, not exactly a single result.

You will get exact match for your condition when you do filter on it.
So try adding filter.